# Does firebase dynamic links needs to append 'page.link' after domain?

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I want to send a short link generated from firebase dynamic link through SMS, but its long as it contains `https://domain.link.page/someString` and someString can be minimum of 4 characters.

Is there any other way to do this with a shorter link?

Comment: on the same page.link domain. Am getting trouble launching apps unlike what used to be back then <appurl>.app.goo.gl/